# How does bash handle operator precedence

Tags: bash, logical-operators, operator-precedence

I have a problem with bash precedence operators, I can't seem to find a logical way of how bash ordering multi commands whit chain operator.

First command : `ls && ls || lds && ls || ls || ls`

Second command : `ls && lds || lds && ls || ls || ls`

How does evaluate the above commands?
In a more a general way how bash handle multi command separated by operator

Comment: They both have an equal precedence, see `PAGER='less +/\ Lists' man bash` but short circuits like that is considered a bad practice, they are short but you get electrocuted in the end... see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf22

Answer (score 2):

- `a || b` - execute `b` if and only if `a` exited with non-zero status (i.e. fail/false)
- `a && b` - execute `b` if and only if `a` exited with zero status (i.e. success/true)

---

Assuming `ls` always succeeds (zero exit status) and `lds` always fails (non-zero exit status):

First command : `ls && ls || lds && ls || ls || ls`

1. `ls` succeeds; operator is `&&` so try second command
2. `ls` succeeds; operator is `||` so skip third command
3. cumulative status is "true"; operator is `&&` so try fourth command
4. `ls` succeeds; operator is `||` so skip fifth command
5. cumulative status is "true"; operator is `||` so skip sixth command
6. done

Demonstration using `echo` / `cd` instead of `ls` / `lds`:

```
$ echo ok1 && echo ok2 || cd /fail3 && echo ok4 || echo ok5 || echo ok6
ok1
ok2
ok4
$
```

Second command : `ls && lds || lds && ls || ls || ls`

1. `ls` succeeds; operator is `&&` so try second command
2. `lds` fails; operator is `||` so try third command
3. `lds` fails; operator is `&&` so skip fourth command
4. cumulative status is "false"; operator is `||` so try fifth command
5. `ls` succeeds; operator is `||` so skip sixth command
6. done

Demonstration:

```
$ echo ok1 && cd /fail2 || cd /fail3 && echo ok4 || echo ok5 || echo ok6
ok1
bash: cd: /fail2: No such file or directory
bash: cd: /fail3: No such file or directory
ok5
$
```

Comment: I want to add that after the test on my terminal the answer given here do not correspond to what bash outputed to me indeed for the command : ls && ls || lds && ls || ls || ls : 3 ls were printed on the terminal whereas this example assume that only two ls will be printed out same for the second command were the output is not the same as stated here. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @dieri my original writeup was wrong

Answer (score 0):

https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/opprecedence.html

In general, `&&` has the same precedence as `||`, so they are executed left to right. You can use parentheses though.

Comment: Worth noting that when adding "parentheses" for operator precedence you will probably want `{ }`, not `( )`. Parentheses run the commands in a subshell, curly brackets don't.

Comment: I am currently implementing a subshell, what is the specifity of expression between parenthese ?

Comment: @dieri Here's the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Execution-Environment). The jist is that variables you create/change in a subshell won't be changed outside the subshell, and the subshell does not inherit its parent's traps.