More than one if statements
Hi I'm looking at writing a script with the parameters for Teams Classic.
Condition
do i have Teams Clssic.app and is it running
if i have Teams Classic.app and its not running
delete it
if i have Teams Classic.app and its running
stop app
then delete it
So far I have the following code written out, but can't see how I can use this if statement to meet all my condition
if [ -d "/Applications/Microsoft Teams classic.app" ] || [ -d "/Applications/Microsoft Teams.app" ] && [ (ps aux | grep Microsoft\ Teams\ Classic.app | grep -v grep > /dev/null) ] then
    echo RUNNING
    killall "Microsoft Teams Classic.app"
    rm -rf /Applications/Microsoft\ Teams\ Classic.app
    rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.teamsclassic.plist
    rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.teamsclassic
    rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/com.microsoft.teamsclassic
else
    echo STOPPED
fi


You should use parentheses to group the || conditions together in the if statement. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74971607/how-does-bash-handle-operator-precedence for the precedence rules.

other than that, it looks like it should work.

Why do you check for  the directory /Applications/Microsoft Teams.app? All the rest of the code only works for Microsoft Teams Classic.

The part after the && does not make sense to me. Don't you get a syntax error?

@Barmar I wanted to check if teams is in the directory. I guess u can eliminate the other portion.

My code still looks broken. Not sure where it’s wrong

The part with grep shouldn't be inside []

Let me test this

as @Barmar asked, why check for the -d directory, check for the file -f instead
